# create a transparent grid on top of QImage

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to build a paint app that has a grid, but I don't want to grid to be included in the saved photo.
I tried to draw on a transparent image, but I got a black background instead!

Here is the full code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QGuiApplication, QImage, QPainter, QPen, QIcon, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QTextEdit, QAction, QFileDialog,
    QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsProxyWidget, QGraphicsView

import pyautogui
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




class Drawer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._drawing = False
        self.last_point = QPoint()

        self.image_layer = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_RGB32)
        self.image_layer.fill(Qt.gray)

        self.brushSize = 2
        self.brushColor = Qt.black

        #paint = QPainter(self.image_layer)
        #paint.setCompositionMode(QtGui.QPainter.CompositionMode_Clear)

        # paint.drawLine(0,0,self.size().width(),0)
        # paint.drawLine(0,10,200,10)

        #paint.drawLine(0,0,0,200)
        #paint.drawLine(10,0,10,200)
        self.update()


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self._drawing = True
        self.last_point = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self._drawing and event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            painter = QPainter(self.image_layer)
            painter.setPen(
                QPen(
                    self.brushColor,
                    self.brushSize,
                    Qt.SolidLine,
                    Qt.RoundCap,
                    Qt.RoundJoin,
                )
            )
            painter.drawLine(self.last_point, event.pos())
            self.last_point = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(QPoint(), self.image_layer)
        painter.end()


    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        if (
                self.size().width() > self.image_layer.width()
                or self.size().height() > self.image_layer.height()
        ):
            qimg = QImage(
                max(self.size().width(), self.image_layer.width()),
                max(self.size().height(), self.image_layer.height()),
                QImage.Format_RGB32,
            )
            qimg.fill(Qt.gray)
            painter = QPainter(qimg)
            painter.drawImage(QPoint(), self.image_layer)
            painter.drawLine(0, 0, qimg.size().width(), 0)
            painter.drawLine(0, 10, qimg.size().width(), 10)
            painter.drawLine(0, 600, qimg.size().width(), 600)
            print(qimg.size().height())
            painter.end()
            self.image_layer = qimg
            self.update()

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        [x, y] = pyautogui.size()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, x, y)

        self.drawer = Drawer()
        textbox = QTextEdit("Converted text will show here")

        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        vlay = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        vlay.addWidget(textbox)
        vlay.addWidget(self.drawer, stretch=1)

        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu("File")

        saveAction = QAction(QIcon("icons/save.png"), "Save", self)
        saveAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
        fileMenu.addAction(saveAction)
        saveAction.triggered.connect(self.save)


    def save(self):
        filePath, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self.drawer, "Save Image", "",
                                                  "PNG(*.png);;JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg);;All Files(*.*) ")

        if filePath == "":
            return
        self.drawer.image_layer.save(filePath)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Note: there are only two lines that mimics the grid, I can draw it later, but for now I want the saved image to not include the grind lines.

Comment: Please always try to make your code as [minimal and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as possible. Everything unrelated to the matter at hand (and there's a lot of that in your example) is just distracting and makes answering questions harder than it should be.

Comment: I will. Thank you.

Comment: I have made the question as minimal and reproducible and removed unrelated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should paint the grid in the paintEvent, instead of continuously painting it onto the image.

```
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(QPoint(), self.image_layer)

        gridSize = 10
        x = y = 0
        width = self.width()
        height = self.height()
        while y <= height:
            # draw horizontal lines
            painter.drawLine(0, y, width, y)
            y += gridSize
        while x <= width:
            # draw vertical lines
            painter.drawLine(x, 0, x, height)
            x += gridSize
```

Comment: Can I the reason behind it? you are using there image in painter.drawImage(), so what is the difference and why the grid is not showing on the saved pic?

Comment: @FarouK when a widget is going to be shown Qt sends it a paint event, and the `paintEvent` is responsible of actually "show" itself to the user. With standard widgets (buttons, combos, etc) their base implementation of `paintEvent()` "paint" the widget. QWidget is an "empty" widget, so nothing is drawn, but if you subclass it and override its `paintEvent()` you can draw whatever you want. What appears is not permanent: it's only what the user can actually see on its screen. So you can use that to show a grid *and* your QImage within the GUI, but this doesn't change the QImage contents.